# Loss of information after resizing the image using skimage python library

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, scikit-image

I am using the following function to resize an image set having shape `(samples, 1, image_row, image_column)`. I am using the `skimage` library.

```
from skimage import io
from skimage.transform import resize   
def preprocess(imgs):
imgs_p = np.ndarray((imgs.shape[0], imgs.shape[1], img_rows, img_cols), dtype=np.uint8)
for i in range(imgs.shape[0]):
    imgs_p[i, 0]  = resize(imgs[i, 0], (img_rows, img_cols))
return imgs_p
```

However, I noticed that the resized images kind of becomes 0-1 array. Here are some testing results. We can see the resized image consists of only 0-1 value. I ma not sure what's wrong with my resize function.

```
   print(image[0,0].shape)

   (420, 580)
   print(image[0,0])
[[  0 155 152 ...,  87  91  90]
  [  0 255 255 ..., 140 141 141]
  [  0 255 255 ..., 157 156 158]
    ...,
  [  0  77  63 ..., 137 133 122]
  [  0  77  63 ..., 139 136 127]
  [  0  77  64 ..., 149 144 137]]

  print(resized_image[0,0].shape)
  (96, 128)
  print(resized_image[0,0])
  [[1 1 0 ..., 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
     ...,
   [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]
   [0 0 0 ..., 0 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your images will be converted to floating points when resized.  There is an optional boolean flag that `transform.resize()` takes: `preserve_range`.  From the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/02ea075fc8207f95fb00914e98ac8e63bddcd67e/skimage/transform/_warps.py)

> **preserve_range**: bool, optional.  Whether to keep the original range of values.  Otherwise, the input image is converted according to the conventions of `img_as_float`.

Set this to `True` and it should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The output of `resize` has a dtype of float, hence it is in the 0-1 range.  You can convert your image back to uint8 range with:

```
from skimage import img_as_ubyte
image = img_as_ubyte(image)
```

Please see the [user guide](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/data_types.html) for a full description of data types and their ranges.